# Incorrectly calculating dialog box position because of dynamic image loading?

Tags: image, mustache, templating, prefetch

I'm working on a gallery type application - one template puts together a popup dialog for a larger view of thumbnail images when clicked.  The server path to the image is included as a template variable.

```
Gallery.Templates.Popup = "\
    <div class='popup'>\
        <img class='popup-image' src='{{image-path}}' />\
        <div class='name'>{{name}}</div>\
        <div class='caption'>{{caption}}</div>\
        <div class='dimensions'>{{dimensions}}</div>\
        <div class='price'>{{price}}</div>\
    </div> \
";
```

This works very well EXCEPT for the first time the image is loaded.  The dialog is constructed and shown but at the time the html string is attached to the dom, it lacks the image.  The problem it is causing is in positioning the dialog:

The dialog box is positioned in the middle of the screen like this:
left = window.width /2  -  dialog.width/2

But since the image is not present, the dialog.width variable is incorrect.  Again, this only happens the first time a thumbnail is clicked, I'm guessing the image is cached for subsequent clicks.

Would this be handled by prefetching the images somehow?  If so, do they need to be attached to the dom in order to be cached or can I just load them in an array?

Many Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the image size ahead of time from the server, you could use that to help you size the '.popup' div appropriately.

It sounds like a bad idea to prefetch images if they aren't needed and I can't think of a way to ensure that a specific image is loaded before it's html is generated programmatically.